# Can I have an horizontal panel using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently use jquery mobile horizontal panel:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/panels/

Is it possible to have the same using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely do the above panels using `Bootstrap`.

Check the following Third Party Libraries.

http://rosskevin.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/material-design/drawers/

http://carolineamaba.com/bootstrap-drawer/

Easy tutorials are available in w3schools.com

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp